# Are Lists just a hack to represent sequences functionally?

Tags: functional-programming

I'm very interested in functional programming as a way to represent abstractions without lying as to what they truly are for convenience. Something feels off to me about lists (in the way they are recursively defined in functional programming).

Why do functional programming languages generally have lists defined with an `Empty` case? Is a collection of things really a sum-type? Or is my conception of a list separate from what this is:

```
type List = Empty | Element head (List tail)
```

I know that pattern matching makes the above safe to do, but to me it seems analogous to making all types [Option types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Option_type) by default.

Is there a term for the right-hand side of this `List` definition?

Also is this `List` something from Mathematics? Are we representing things which are truly [sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence) as lists for convenience?

Comment: It's pretty much exactly the same base case/recursive case structure as in a recursive algorithm. Base case/recursive case is an extremely common pattern.

Comment: How would you represent empty lists without an `Empty` case? If you only had the second case lists would all be infinite.

Comment: I was more asking on the validity of the List data structure as a representation of a true concept. The fact that a sequence includes the Empty set in a sum-type makes it seem like an imperfect representation of something simpler. Not really a rational question, so I apologize if it's confusing - the answerer articulated my question much better than I did.

"... you wonder whether lists are an adequate model of sequences. In programming terms, answering this question involves defining the abstract data type of sequences ..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very natural way to define a type of *finite* lists is to state: a list is either empty, or the addition of an element at (say) the front of an existing list. This is what the recursive sum type you refer to represents. An option type is simply another kind of sum type that represents two possibilities: either it does not contain a payload, or it does. The two types, lists and options, represent different things.

I have sometimes seen constructors of recursive types, like lists, classified as *base constructors* or *recursive constructors*, paralleling their use in proofs by structural induction. This makes clear what you mean, although other people may use slightly different terms.

On the one hand, the type of lists thus defined is a perfectly legitimate mathematical entity. On the other, you wonder whether lists are an adequate *model* of sequences. In programming terms, answering this question involves defining the *abstract data type* of sequences, including their desired properties, and proving that implementing sequences via lists satisfies those properties. For example, from the article you link:

> The number of elements (possibly infinite) is called the length of the sequence.

So, if you want to represent infinite sequences, the type of finite lists by itself will be insufficient. The section on formal definitions in the same article considers sequences as functions, and this may be another way to model them. Finite lists are a simple, reasonable candidate to represent finite sequences.